# Eclipse Helios Svn e VPN Client

Tags: eclipse, svn, windows-8

Uso uma VPN para acessar serviços remotamente do servidor de um cliente. Um deles é o svn.
A minha URL de conexão é do tipo https://svn.meusite.com.br/svn
Testei no Tortoise funciona perfeitamente, mas no Eclipse Helios o servidor não aceita a conexão.

Já tentei reinstalar os plugins do svn e também não funcionou.

Outros repositorios fora da VPN funcionam no eclipse.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que poderia ser?

Answer (score 1):

É muito provável que você esteja conectada a um servidor proxy. Verifique se isto procede e configure seu eclipse usando o menu *Preferences -> Network Connections*.